# Update DataSet structure programmatically

Tags: vb.net

I have a mysql table, (lets call it tableA) to which users can add new columns. I then have a rdlc report which takes it source from a typed dataset (datasetA) that is based on tableA. My problem is that when users add new columns to tableA, I need to be able to refresh or re-create datasetA as well as the rdlc dataset that takes its source from datasetA. And I need to be able to do this programmatically when new columns are created in tableA. I am using visual studio 2015

Comment: so basically you want to automate the creation / update of an RDLC report?

Comment: I dont want to re-create the rdlc at runtime. Keep in mind the columns in the underlying table will keep changing. I have found a way using parameters to assign the table fields to to the rdlc columns. But when the table columns change, because those changes are not updated in the typed dataset and rdlc dataset, I get errors in the report because even thought the new table columns are passed to the rdlc using parameters, those columns don't exist in the typed dataset and rdlc dataset. So I need to automate the creation or update of the typed dataset that the rdlc relies on

Comment: well how do you create that dataset currently? Did you write it by hand? Or use some tool to generate it?

Comment: The dataset is the normal .xsd file created by =>Project =>Add New Item => Dataset. From there I choose the table and select the fields I want. In this case I use `SELECT * FROM...`, which I know is a bad idea in production but I dont have another choice to get columns for a table that may be changed by the user